# How to handle Apple Pencil events in Qt?

Tags: ios, qt, pyqt5, stylus-pen

Has anyone figure out how to get events from Apple Pencil in Qt-5.7+? It looks like it sends a single QEvent.TouchBegin just like a finger, but no QEvent.TouchUpdate, and so also no pressure values.

If not, then maybe someone has written some objective C to handle the UITouch events and send it to Qt somehow?

I am actually writing this app with PyQt5, but I would settle for just getting an event to Qt in C++ so I could take it from there!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check on Qt's bugtracker?

Comment: Yes. And just submitted a bug for 5.7.2. Too bad, if I were to somehow find a way to edit the qt source (would take some learning), building a static qt for iOS triggers other problems for my toolchain...

Comment: Please share the link to your report here -- so that if other people get in trouble they will find it.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59042

Comment: Have you tried adding `qDebug() << event` to your `QEvent::event(QEvent *)` reimplementation, and looking at the debug output? It could be that the events are delivered, but are not what you expect them to be.

Comment: Kuba: I did some debugging in quiview.mm to get arrive at the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

After moving to a developer build of Qt and doing some debugging I learned that there are two problems:

1. (as stated in the docs) you have to accept the TouchBegin event in
   order to receive subsequent TouchUpdate events.
2. The detection of touch pressure is broken for iPad Pro in Qt-5.7.1.
   I updated the bug with this info.

I have submitted a bug to qt for this behavior, including my fix: [QTBUG-59042 Apple Pencil not properly supported on iOS](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59042)